# Two tables join with foreigns keys

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Let get straight to the code.
I've tried to return a list of movies with inner join tabel of categories. Failed at it so far.

```
public int FilmID { get; private set; }
public string FilmName { get; set; }
public string FilmDescription { get; set; }
public int FilmYear { get; set; }
public string FkCategoryID { get; set; }
```

I'm pretty new to linq so It is probably wrong.

```
    public List<Movie> TakeOutAllMovies()
{
    var WholeList = (from movies in db.films 
                    join cat in db.categories on movies equals cat.category_id
                    select new Movie{FilmID = movies.film_id, FilmName = movies.film_navn, FilmDescription = movies.film_description,
                                       FilmYear = movies.film_year, FkCategoryID = movies.categories.category_navn}).ToList();

    return WholeList;
}
```

It gives a fail of course `the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect`.

I wanted to put in place of fkCategoryID a name of category from table categories instead of just ID. Am I doing it right?

Comment: is this entity framework or linq to sql or other?

Comment: @DanielA.White linq to sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not join the `Movie` with the `category_id` but the Movie's `FkCategoryId`:

So instead of

```
from movies in db.films          
join cat in db.categories on movies equals cat.category_id
```

this way:

```
from movies in db.films 
join cat in db.categories on movies.FkCategoryID equals cat.category_id
```

Comment: Can't belive I forgot that. 'Feels dumb'. Thank you thought :3